# How to Package Watch App within Cordova App

Tags: ios, cordova, xamarin.ios, watchkit, telerik-appbuilder

We have a cross-platform cordova app developed using Telerik AppBuilder, and a WatchKit app (extension + watchkit app) built using Xamarin Studio. I don't know what the proper steps are for bundling the compiled Extension (the .appex, right?) and the IPA output by Telerik AppBuilder.

Given the breadth of technologies that we're using, I don't even know where I should start to look for this process. I've noticed that I can access IPA contents like most any other ZIP archive, but don't know if that's even the right first step...

Comment: Why are you mixing these two competing technologies?

Comment: It was simply how development worked out for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is posible to achieve this by editing the `.ipa` file of the main Cordova application. In general one should add the `.appex` file under `Plugins` folder, create `.entitlements` file for the host iPhone/iPad application and finally re-codesign the binary and zip the `Payload` to an `.ipa` file again. Below are steps describing how to combine Cordova app developed using Telerik AppBuilder and a WatchKit app (extension + watchkit app).

1. First off you need to have the `.ipa` file for your host application and the `.appex` package for the WatchKit app. An `.ipa` file is a regular iOS application archive file which can be uncompressed like any other archive. For instance you can use `unzip` command line tool (e.g. `unzip <my_ipa_file>.ipa`). Unzip both the Telerik AppBuilder `.ipa` and the WatchKit app.
    
   **Note:** *Each `.ipa` archive contains folder named `Payload` where the actual `.app` application package is located. One should keep this naming convension when zipping back this folder.*
2. Delete the `_CodeSignature` folder at `Payload/<cordova_application_name>.app/_CodeSignature`. The `_CodeSignature` folder contains xml file which represents a hash table created during the application binary codesign process. It contains information mainly regarding app resources. We don't need this because our aim is to generate new one.
3. Copy the `.appex` WatchKit extension into `Payload/cordova_application_name>.app/Plugins` (you will most likely have to create the `Plugins` folder).
4. Create `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent` by using the template

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>application-identifier</key>
       <string>'App_Identifier_Prefix'.'Main_Application_Bundle_Identifier'</string>
       <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
       <array>
           <string>'App_Identifier_Prefix'.'Main_Application_Bundle_Identifier'</string>
       </array>
   </dict>
   </plist>`

Add the `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent` under `Payload/<cordova_application_name>.app/archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent`

**Note:** *The `Main_Application_Bundle_Identifier` is the `CFBundleIdentifier` value of your cordova application. For more about `App_Identifier_Prefix` check this SO question [Changing manually $(AppIdentifierPrefix) property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473443/changing-manually-appidentifierprefix-property?lq=1)*

5. All `.mobileprovision` files should use the correct app IDs and same certificate. I'd recommend that initially the `.ipa` file of the cordova application be signed with the correct `.mobileprovision` provision. Otherwise you should place your `.mobileprovision` under `Payload/<cordova_application_name>.app/embedded.mobileprovision`.
6. Use `codesign` tool to re-sign the binary of the Cordova application.

   `codesign -f -s "Certificate_Name" --entitlements Payload/<cordova_application_name>.app/archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent Payload/<cordova_application_name>.app/<cordova_application_name>`
7. Zip the edited `Payload` back to `.ipa` file. (e.g. `zip -r <expected_ipa_name>.ipa Payload/`)
8. We are good to go!

Let me know if you need any further assistence on the issue.

Comment: I'd like to take you up on the offer of further assistance.  I'm trying to use the plugin [cordova-plugin-apple-watch](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch) and still can't seem to get things right.  I'm willing to donate to the cause of your choice or put up a bounty etc... Not sure how to ask for help.  But it's basically has anyone found or are they willing to share a sample Cordvoa project that uses the Apple Watch plugin above, where the sample includes the requisite project settings like those above?  Feel free to offline message too and thanks!

Comment: Hi, @DavidGerding ! Support for WatchOS 2.0 is under development and will be released by Telerik's AppBuilder most likely by the end of January. Follow the plugin page on https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/AppleWatch for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  The challenge for me is I can't use Telerik's plugin because we need more control over the app ux and event wiring than are available in the declarative js elements ... But maybe the new version will have the functionality we need.  In case you're interested or available my offer of supporting/motivating a "working example" of the [Apple Watch Plugin](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch) stands :)  for posting here and / or in the issues page on git for that plugin stands.