# How to obtain the app ID programmatically in Swift?

Tags: swift, app-id

In a macOS app, I'm using this code to create a directory in Application Support folder.

```
let directoryURL = appSupportURL.appendingPathComponent("com.myCompany.myApp").appendingPathComponent("Documents")
```

How can the string **com.myCompany.myApp** obtained programmatically in Swift?

I saw this question but I'm not sure how to use it in my macOS Swift app: [Access App Identifier Prefix programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726672/access-app-identifier-prefix-programmatically/11841898#11841898)

Comment: If you sandbox your app, this is a non-problem. Your Application Support folder is yours alone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
    appSupportURL.appendingPathComponent("\(bundleIdentifier)").appendingPathComponent("Documents")
}
```

Little explanation: Property bundleIdentifier is optional, therefore you have to safely-unwrap the value and then you won't be asked for any exclamation mark :)

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple to get the app ID :

```
let bundleIdentifier =  Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
  appSupportURL.appendingPathComponent("\(bundleIdentifier)").appendingPathComponent("Documents")
```

A bundle identifier is the string assigned to the CFBundleIdentifier key in the bundle’s Info.plist file. This string is typically formatted using reverse-DNS notation so as to prevent name space conflicts with developers in other companies. For example, a Finder plug-in from Apple might use the string com.apple.Finder.MyGetInfoPlugin as its bundle identifier. Rather than passing a pointer to a bundle object around your code, clients that need a reference to a bundle can simply use the bundle identifier to retrieve it

For more details & other operation's details, please check

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html